# Providing "resource" argument to CloudLoggingHandler class does't work

Tags: python, django, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

Providing `resource` argument to `CloudLoggingHandler` class doesn't work, that is, it cannot logging to `stackdriver`. If I comment `resource` out, it works fine. I also tried a simple python script that doesn't run in Django, it worked fine too.

This actually my Django LOGGING handlers settings:

```js
'handlers': {
    'stderr': {
        'class': 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler',
        'name': "name",
        'resource': Resource(
            type="container",
            labels={
                ...
            },
        ),
        'client': google.cloud.logging.Client()
    },
},
```

No `resource`, No problem:

```js
'handlers': {
    'stderr': {
        'class': 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler',
        'name': "name",
        'client': google.cloud.logging.Client()
    },
},
```

A simple script works too:

```
import logging
import google.cloud.logging # Don't conflict with standard logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler, setup_logging
from google.cloud.logging.resource import Resource

client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO) # defaults to WARN

res = Resource(
    type="container",
    labels={
       ...
    },
)
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client, name='name', resource=res)
setup_logging(handler)
logging.error('logging!')
```

I use `google-cloud-logging` version is `1.10.0`.
Can someone give some suggestions about debugging `stackdriver` logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is most likely caused by the resource being malformed, either because the type is not supported (or no longer supported), because the labels do not match those expected for the given type, because required labels  are missing, or because special permission is required to write logs against the specific resource type in question.

In this particular case, the use of `container` rather than `k8s_container` looks suspicious. Based on [this conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-stackdriver-discussion/Llt6VxIDunc) as well as the existence of `k8s_container` in the list of [Stackdriver Monitoring resource types](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources) as well as [Stackdriver Logging resource types](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-types), whereas `container` is documented only on the latter, this is likely a deprecated resource type that has been supplanted by `k8s_container`.

If that does not work, failures to write the remote logs should produce logs locally (or using whatever handlers have been attached to the [background thread transport](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/logging/google/cloud/logging/handlers/transports/background_thread.py)); though those logs are obviously harder to access, if you can get to those logs, it should be possible to see what went wrong with the attempt to write to Stackdriver Logging.